# JavaScript requesting file with inherited protocol

Tags: http, appcelerator

I have a titanium app that is embedding some third-party JavaScript code that is making a request for more files that it uses. The problem is that these file are being requested with the inherited-style protocol (`//example.com/file.js`) and it seems Titanium is attempting to reference this request as a local file. If I run the app in an iOS simulator and debug in Safari, the following console message is shown:

`[Error] Failed to load resource: resource unavailable file://www.documentcloud.org/documents/2179503-superior-court-lawsuit-intersal-v-nc.js?_=1465333443448`

Has anybody else ran into this issue or know of a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, the final app is a native app. It is not possible to include external JavaScript files like it is in a browser/webview.

Yes, there still is JavaScript in the final, native, app. But it does not come with anything for you to load external Javascript.

If you want to include an external javascript file you will need to package it with the app.

It might also be possible to fetch an external Javascript file using the http client and storing it locally, however I have not tried this and do not recommend this.

In your case, just fetch the data as JSON by changing the `.js` in the url to `.json`: http://www.documentcloud.org/documents/2179503-superior-court-lawsuit-intersal-v-nc.json?_=1465333443448

You can then just fetch this with http client and use the data as usual

Comment: The problem is that we're basically embedding a third party javascript file and that file is then making the request in its code. We have no control over the protocol.

Comment: the 3rd party javascript file is still located inside the app/in your codebase right? You will have to change the code or redo yourself to fix it

Comment: For what it's worth, this is all in a WebView. So my assumption was that it would / should honor these types of URLs.